# Chatter feeds of logged in user using mobile sdk

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, android

I am playing around with the mobile sdk and in the mobile sdk sample contactExplorer, i am adding a functionality of getting the chatter feeds of the logged in user.

In my index.html

i added a href tag to display a new link to fetch the chatter feed

```
<p><a href="#" id="link_fetch_sfdc_chatter" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Fetch Chatter</a></p>
```

and in the inline.js i added the following code

```
$j('#link_fetch_sfdc_chatter').click(function() {
                                     logToConsole("link_fetch_sfdc_chatter clicked");
                                            forcetkClient.chatterFeedsCurrentUser(onSuccessSfdcChatter, onErrorSfdc); 
                                     });
```

Here i am calling a function to get the feeds and pass the response to callback method onSuccessSfdcAccounts.

here is the chatterFeedsCurrentUser method on my forcetk.mobilesdk.js

```
  forcetk.Client.prototype.chatterFeedsCurrentUser = function(callback, error) {
alert('calling from forcetk');
    return this.ajax('/' + this.apiVersion + '/chatter/feeds/news/me/feed-items', callback, error);
}
```

Here is the onSuccessSfdcChatter method

```
function onSuccessSfdcChatter(response) {
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    alert('Chatter success method!');
    cordova.require("salesforce/util/logger").logToConsole("onSuccessSfdcChatter: received " + response.totalSize + " Feed Items");


}
```

The issue i am facing is that chatterFeedsCurrentUser method is not calling the callback method. The alert 'calling from forcetk' is only displayed after which nothing happens. I am not sure what i am doing wrong here.

I am working on hybrid app on a android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your success method is actually named `onSuccessSfdcChatter` while the method you are registering as a callback with forcetk is called `onSuccessSfdcAccounts`- make sure you use the correct success method handler name that's registered with forcetk

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.. I had originaly had it as `onSuccessSfdcChatter` and i had changed that out just to see if it was calling the `onSuccessSfdcAccounts`. In both cases call is not passing into the success methods. So i am thinking that its got to be something in  `forcetk.Client.prototype.chatterFeedsCurrentUser` which is causing the trouble but unable to identify what it is

Comment: This gist has some examples of using forcetk for Chatter feed operations. I would recommend you look at this code, you're definitely missing something if your callback function is not being triggered - https://gist.github.com/sbob-sfdc/3644128